# Closures in C# with lambdas and anonymous methods

Tags: c#, closures

I'd like to ask question related to Closures maintaining local variable basing on two examples:

```csh
public static Func<int, int> F2()
{
    var local = 1;
    Func<int, int> inc = delegate (int x)
    {
        local = local + 1;
        return x + local;
    };
    return inc;
}
```

Now, calling this renders proper Closure working mechanism

```
var inc2 = F2();
Console.WriteLine(inc2(10));
Console.WriteLine(inc2(10));
```

Results with output:

```
12
13
```

Now, alternate version:

```
public static Func<int, int> F1 = i =>
{
    var local = 1;
    Func<int, int> FInn = x =>
    {
        local++;
        return local + x;
    };
    return FInn(i);
};
```

Calling this one:

```
    var inc1 = F1;
    Console.WriteLine(inc1(10));
    Console.WriteLine(inc1(10));
```

Renders now:

```
12
12
```

Why second version works in other manner than first ?

thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first example, `local` is initialized at the top, and the inner lambda captures it. You return the inner lambda to the calling code, which includes the captured variable.

In the second example, every time you are invoking `F1`, you run it from the very beginning. This means you're initializing the `local` variable to 1 every time. Then you immediately execute the inner `FInn` right away against it.

---

To be clear: this has nothing to do with the first example using a delegate instead of the terser lambda syntax. You can write the first example with `inc` implemented as a lambda instead of a delegate, and you'd still see this difference.

Comment: Yeah, I see the problem with re-initialization during debugging. In first example, expression var local = 1 is called only in the very beginning, while later it's called every time. However I don't have any idea, while calling inc2(10) omits var local=1 and executes inner delegate.

Comment: I can understand the confusion. The chief difference between the two approaches is that the first one returns the nested lambda, while the second one returns the outer lambda. Since `local` is initialized as part of the outer lambda, that makes a difference.

Comment: Great ! Thank you again.